# question proof of fundamental theorem of curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

hey i use this proof of the fundamental theorem of curves:

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-fundamental-theorem-of-space-curves

but i dont understand the step at (3)

why do the dot products equal 1? because they are parametrisized by arc length?
and why is T1=T2, N1=N2, B1=B2?
how do i know?

Comment: They're all unit vectors.

Comment: @Randall ok thanks and why do i need that its =3? how do i get from there to T1=T2, N1=N2, B1=B2? can you please explain?

Comment: They say that the "Frenet frames coincide."  And if $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector, what is $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}$?

Comment: u ⋅ u = 1. and i understand why its =3. but what has the result 3 to do with the outcome, that T1=T2, .... why do i need to know the result 3?

Comment: @Randall? why do i need the result 3?please help me. its important for me to understand